# ng-repeat a block of html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two input forms, **Date To** and **Date From** that I want to repeat using **ng-repeat**. Right now, it's a block oh HTML text and I'm not sure what's the most efficient way of doing this except concatinating all the div elements the **js** side with the plus symbol.

ex. `'<div class="container"> + bla bla + ...'`

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <!--Time From-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 date-and-time-from" >
                        <label>Date/Time From</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="date-field">
                                <ms-date-time-picker ng-model="newResource.booking[0].startDateTime" placeholder="From"></ms-date-time-picker>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Time To-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 date-and-time-to" >
                        <label>Date/Time To</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="date-field">
                                <ms-date-time-picker ng-model="newResource.booking[0].endDateTime" placeholder="To" ></ms-date-time-picker>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The goal of my application is that a user chooses how many bookings he will store in his array in the first modal. Then he clicks a button, and the above html text will appear in the second modal. Based on the number of bookings the user chooses (let's say 3), the html above will repeat 3 times in a modal (there will be 3 Date From/Date To forms in a vertical list).

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

[image: example of the above code]

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here;  your question asks about `ng-repeat` but your code doesn't show an `ng-repeat` in use.  Beyond that, it's not clear why you would need to "concatinating all the div elements the js side with the plus symbol.".... That doesn't really sound like you are using `ng-repeat` at all.

Comment: Your question is pretty much vague to give an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to use ng-repeat just go through [the documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).
I see that in your question you are appending divs like:

```
htmlString ='<div id="1">Bla</div>'+'<div id="2">Bla</div>';
```

`ngRepeat directive` will be used on the HTML itself. Like this:

```
arrayOfItems = [1,2,3]; //in your controller
<!-- in your html -->
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfItems" id="{{item}}"> 
  Bla
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Modals HTML**

```
Number of bookings: 
<input type="text" ng-model="numberOfBooking" name="numberOfBooking" />
<button type="button" ng-click="confirmNumberOfBooking()">Confirm Booking</button>
```

**First Modal Controller**

```
$scope.numberOfBooking = 1;
$scope.newResource.bookings = [
  {
    fromDateAndTime: "datetime",
    toDateAndTime: "datetime"
  }
];

$scope.confirmNumberOfBooking = confirmNumberOfBooking;
function confirmNumberOfBooking(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.numberOfBooking; i++){ 
    $scope.newResource.bookings.push({fromDateAndTime: "datetime",toDateAndTime: "datetime"});
    }
}
```

**Second Modal HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="booking in newResource.bookings track by $index">
    <!--Time From-->
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 date-and-time-from" >
           <label>Date/Time From</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9">
         <div class="form-group">
            <span class="date-field">
            <ms-date-time-picker ng model="newResource.booking[$index].startDateTime" placeholder="From"></ms-date-time-picker>
            </span>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>

     <!--Time To-->
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 date-and-time-to" >
           <label>Date/Time To</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
           <div class="form-group">
              <span class="date-field">
                 <ms-date-time-picker ng-model="newResource.booking[$index].endDateTime" placeholder="To" ></ms-date-time-picker>
               </span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```